# Can I use iOS AutoFill feature only in app without associated domain?

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering if I can use AutoFill without implementing the Associated Domains?

So this means for example that when the user register in my app that I save the credentials.

And then when he tries to login offer this credentials as AutoFill option.

Is something like that even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can take advantage of AutoFill without setting up associated domains. The part you'll miss out on is that iCloud/1Password/etc. won't be able to suggest the right log in details for your app without the associated domains set up. Instead, it'll prompt the user to choose/search for the matching log in details and select them from a list. But it should fill it in for you fine, especially if you add the extra details like setting `textContentType` on your text fields so iOS knows what's a log in form in your app.

**ETA:** Actually, I ended up having issues with AutoFill in my app that seemed to be fixed by setting up associated domains. The documentation makes it seem like that step is optional, but I had trouble where 1Password would let me choose the log in details but not fill them into the text fields until I had associated domains set up, whereas iCloud seemed to work fine mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Generating passwords and saving credentials via keychain will not work without associated domains. However, autofill for email, phone number etc. will work even if associated domains are not setup.